# How does .NET efficiently listen for raised events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, clr

Does it use some sort of event thread that polls an event queue? Also, does the technique differ depending on the type of event?  Some events are raised by the program itself, like a button click, while others are raised externally, like the FileCreated event read by the FileSystemWatcher. Are these events handled differently under the hood?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a very broad topic, I can only reasonably cover the basics.  The mechanisms are not specific to .NET, they apply to any program that runs on Windows.  There are two basic ways that the operating system or another program can trigger an event.

The first one is as you assume, the underlying mechanism for a button's Click event as well as almost all of the events that are associated with a GUI program.  The core .NET call is Application.Run(), it starts a dispatcher loop.  Also known as "pumping the message loop".   The general solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  The basic winapi functions that generate the event are SendMessage() and PostMessage().  A .NET program has plumbing that turn these messages in events that you can subscribe, the NativeWindow class is a good example.  Its WndProc() method runs when a message is received.  It in turn can then raise a specific event, based on the specific message.

The second one is where the operating system can make a callback to a function on an arbitrary worker thread, usually one pulled from the threadpool.  FileSystemWatcher is an example of that one, the underlying winapi function that sets it up is ReadDirectoryChangesW().  It supports overlapped I/O, allowing it to operate asynchronously.  In other words, you can ask it to start working on the job and return immediately.  The operating system then signals an event or makes a callback when the job is done.  Implicit in the way these kind of events work is that they are fired on an arbitrary thread, unlike the first mechanism.

Learning more about the winapi is necessary to make sense of all this.

Comment: Considering the discussion points of the other answers to yours (involving WinAPI), I suppose the missing piece is referencing IL assembler?

Comment: I have no idea why the other answers are talking about .NET delegates, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

> **TL;DR:** Event listeners do not actually have to actively listen; they get called back by the event-triggering party. See the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Just like properties, which are actually not much more than a group of methods and some syntactic sugar added, .NET events are also not much more than something else (multi-cast delegates) and some syntactic sugar.

And just like with properties, which you can have auto-implemented by the languages (e.g. `string Name { get; set; }`) events are usually also "auto-implemented" in a very similar way (unless you specifically implement an event yourself). If you wanted to implement an event yourself (which is quite a rare thing), it might look like this (simplified):

```
public event Action Completed
{
    add  // gets called for each `obj.Completed += value;`
    {
        if (completed == null)
        {
            completed = new Action(value);
        }
        else
        {
            completed += value;
        }
    }
    remove  // gets called for each `obj.Completed -= value;`
    {
        if (completed != null)
        {
            completed -= value;
        }
    }
}

private Action completed;  // backing field (a delegate) for the event
```

Like most data properties, each event usually also has a backing field — namely, a multi-cast delegate. Subscribing to an event (`Completed += …`) or unsubscribing from it (`-=`) gets translated to calls to the `add` and `remove` accessor methods.

(Multi-cast) delegates have an internal method [invocation list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx). You can add a method via the `+=` operator (as it happens above inside the `add` accessor) or remove it from the invocation list via the `-=` operator (as above in the `remove` accessor). So take note that `+=` and `-=` do different things depending on whether they are applied to an event (invokes `add` or `remove`) or to a delegate (add/remove methods from the internal invocation list via under-the-hood calls to `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove`).

Event subscribers don't have to poll; they will get called when an event is triggered. Whatever party raises/triggers an event actually just invokes the "backing-field" delegate; and invoking that delegate means invoking each method on the delegate's invocation list — i.e., the subscribers' event handler methods.

Comment: ah.. you just updated to reference the observer pattern.. here is a reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx. The relevant section is the *Publishing and Subscribing* section.

Comment: also, this blurb describes methods in the invocation list of a delegate as being two types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664602(v=vs.71).aspx .. instance method and static.. but that isn't really in the context of event delegates.

Comment: This makes sense to me for some sort of internal event, like a Timer event, but how does it attach to WIndows events, like the FileSystemWatcher I mentioned.

edit:  Looks like I should have read the response from Hans Passant, as he addresses this.  Thanks everybody for the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Events use *delegates*. Let's first look at delegates, and then at how they are used by events.

### Delegates

A *delegate* is kind of like a managed function pointer. You can create a delegate that, when invoked,
calls the function it is pointing to. Delegates are type checked, so their parameter types and return type must match the function you want to call. You specify the parameter and return types through a *delegate type*. For example, here I define a delegate type for a function that returns a `string` and takes no arguments:

```
delegate string MyDelegate();
```

Now I can instantiate `MyDelegate` to make it point at whatever function I want. For example, I create a new delegate `d` that points to the `Do` static function, and invoke it. You can try this for yourself:

```
class Program {

    delegate string MyDelegate();

    static string Do() {
        return "DO!";
    }

    static void Main() {
        MyDelegate d = new MyDelegate(Do);

        Console.WriteLine(d());     // Prints: DO!
    }
}
```

The .NET framework has some built-in delegate types you may be familiar with, such as the [`Action<...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) and [`Func<TResult, ...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) families of delegates.

Okay, now we have a basic understanding of delegates. Let's see how they are used in events.

### Events

You usually define a new event like this:

```
event EventHandler Click;
```

Here, [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a pre-defined *delegate type* with this signature:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Note that the delegate corresponds exactly to the event handler you'd write to handle the event:

```
void HandleButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Do something!
}
```

When you register your event handler `HandleButtonClick` to the `Click` event using the `+=` operator, it adds a delegate pointing to your function to the event's *multi-cast delegate*.

```
this.Click += HandleButtonClick;
```

A multi-cast delegate is just like a regular delegate, but it can call multiple functions, one after another in no particular order.

When you use the event, you're actually invoking the delegate to call all those functions:

```
this.Click();
```

---

And now you know how events work: delegates.

Comment: this is a somewhat high level/pragmatic answer, but the question is quite broad... it's helpful anyway